# Is there going to be C++/Qt support in Realm?

Tags: c++, qt, realm

I'm currently developing a cross-platform app in Qt, and need to choose a BAAS platform. So far Realm scores the highest in features and usability, but lacks C++/Qt support. Is it planned for the future?

Comment: read this: https://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/slides/DD12/Qt_DevDays_2012_Sami_Makkonen.pdf

Answer (score 2):

We would love to support C++/Qt in the future. Right now we don't have a firm timeline, but it has been at least superficially discussed. We see opportunity in the IoT space as well where C++ SDK could benefit, but it is still lower in priority compared to the primary mobile platforms.

Comment: In fact I'm using the latest QT 5.8 version to write an Android/iOS cross-platform app

Comment: That's awesome! Sorry I don't have a better answer right now. Will try to update this issue once I have more info, or feel free to email me at af@realm.io if you want to connect directly.

Answer (score 0):

Realm C++ SDK supports Qt:

- [The docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/cpp/)
- [Qt code examples](https://github.com/realm/realm-cpp/tree/main/examples/Qt)
- [Announcement](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/realm/announcing-realm-cplusplus-sdk-alpha/)